# Decoding Html string in mvcContrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

My question is simple.

How do I decode Html characters in mvc contrib grid? I want those to be rendered inside textarea after decoding. But unfortunately its all encoded information what I get inside textarea. Following is how I'm trying to do this...

```
column.For ( cust => Html.TextArea("Customer", new HtmlString(cust.Address), 4, 40, new  { @class = "custAddress" }) ) 
.Named("Address")
.DoNotEncode();
```

Above gives me red underlined error under HtmlString() returned object, which is obviously because TextArea's 2nd argument expects string value instead.

The Address field in database has Turkish characters. All what I get inside my textarea is characters like þlseķ and so on. But I want those information to be decoded, anyhow

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html.TextArea("Customer", (new HtmlString(cust.Address)).ToHtmlString(), 4, 40, new  { @class = "custAddress" })

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the HtmlString?  I tried this and I had unicode characters rendering correctly.

```
column.For ( cust => Html.TextArea("Customer", cust.Address, 4, 40, new  { @class = "custAddress" }) ) 
.Named("Address")
.DoNotEncode();
```